# Modular Arithmetic in Z

Tags: abstract-algebra

Ok, so I was asked to find all solutions to Solve [3][x]=[9] in Z12 and express my answer as the congruence class {x}.

I've done a few problems like this, but Z has always been prime. I'm not even sure to to approach this problem because when I do the extended Euclidean algorithm, I get 12=3(4)+0. Therefore I stopped because I didn't know how to continue to find the u and v vales such that 3u +12v=3.

Any tips on how to approach a problem like this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are not many elements in $\Bbb Z_{12}$ so why not try them all?  Having done so, you might think about what you find so you can solve similar problems with larger groups.  Prime factorization is useful.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can solve $3x=9, 3x=21, 3x=33$ in the usual integers.  The point is that since $12$ is not prime, you do not get the ability to find multiplicative inverses since they don't always exist.  Still another way of "dividing" might make sense once you figure it out.

Comment: *Hint*: $3x - 9 \equiv 0 \pmod{12} \iff 12 \mid 3(x-3)$.